# Error on dump or dd laravel adding a character before result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

All request and dumps in laravel add a ^before a result, that's only do that in dd or dump

[image: exemple of error]

[image: exemple dd Request:all()]

This effect generate a lot of errors on my code, someone past some like that?

Comment: I do not have it.

Comment: i think is a configuration on laravel, i have another project in same server that not show that

Comment: Do a search on your project, you may have hardcoded that character somewhere. Most IDEs have that function (`Find on Path...` on phpstorm)

Comment: Can relate. Same thing happened yesterday after updating to Laravel 6.2

Comment: as it turns out the caret is coming from symphony's package var-dumper.

Comment: Why would this generate errors in your code? `dd` and `dump` are debugging tools, they should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem with laravel framework Lumen (5.8.12) and I solved the problem by returning to version 5.8.4.

The Origin of the problem seems to be the Symfony VarDumper Component
(**\vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Cloner\Data.php**, **line 302**):

```
$dumper->dumpScalar($cursor, 'default', '^');
```

Should be:

```
 $dumper->dumpScalar($cursor, 'default', '');
```

### Update

It is there for a useful reason. In terminal if you hover over the mouse on that `^` sign it will show you the file path from where this dump is coming from! I think it's really a useful thing but I don't see it working in browser. So, it should either be removed from borwser or fix the issue there.

Comment: Thanks, can't get why they added it... asked there https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper/commit/b9e52cb403723d04a8600a270bbaea161e3a6959#r39678570

Answer (score -1):

For simple variables, reading the output should be straightforward. Here are some examples showing first a variable defined in PHP, then its dump representation:
[Check This Link For Better reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#dump-examples-and-output)

For example:

```
 $var = [
'a simple string' => "in an array of 5 elements",
'a float' => 1.0,
'an integer' => 1,
'a boolean' => true,
'an empty array' => [],
 ];
 dump($var);
```

The gray arrow is a toggle button for hiding/showing children of nested structures.

```
$var = "This is a multi-line string.\n";
$var .= "Hovering a string shows its length.\n";
$var .= "The length of UTF-8 strings is counted in terms of UTF-8 characters.\n";
$var .= "Non-UTF-8 strings length are counted in octet size.\n";
$var .= "Because of this `\xE9` octet (\\xE9),\n";
$var .= "this string is not UTF-8 valid, thus the `b` prefix.\n";
dump($var);

class PropertyExample
{
public $publicProperty = 'The `+` prefix denotes public properties,';
protected $protectedProperty = '`#` protected ones and `-` private ones.';
private $privateProperty = 'Hovering a property shows a reminder.';
}

$var = new PropertyExample();
dump($var);
```