# Laravel 5.7 returning a leading ^ character on request and dd response

Tags: laravel

hi i start this new project yesterday and i was doing it config and i encounter this 
no matter which route or request response i see i get ^ at the first if request reponse like

^ "sdoakdpask"

or on request send form form i see 
^ "sdoakdpask" again
i try composer autoload and config the app from first
but nothing has work
but when i test that row project i have at the first with 0 config work right but when i made the smallest change in composer.json like add a require  it get messed up and get like 
^ "sdoakdpask"

tnx in advanced

Comment: can you post your composer.json code?

Comment: i paste it in here https://paste.ubuntu.ir/euup

Comment: dd() had an update where they added that, but why is it important how dd transforms the output?

Comment: since when is there update on laravel and why did this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on dump or dd laravel adding a character before result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146473/error-on-dump-or-dd-laravel-adding-a-character-before-result)